# Obtener resultado de datetimepicker en span

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Estoy obteniendo los resultados de input de texto en spans, pero en el input donde tengo el calendario con datetimepicker, éste no envía el valor. El script funciona bien con los inputs de texto, pero con el que tiene datetimepicker no.

Busque bastante pero no pude dar con la solución, que puede llegar a ser?

```
<input type="text" name="vtoDias2" id="fecha3" placeholder="Ingrese Fecha"> 


<span id="numFecha3"></span>

<script>
 $("input[name=vtoDias2]").on('keyup', function () {
 $('#numFecha3').html($(this).val());
 });  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres al plugin datePicker de jQuery (aunque probablemente te pase igual con otros), el problema probablemente sea que la fecha se toma de un calendario mediante el ratón, no mediante el teclado.

Para detectar cuando cambie el valor debes escuchar el evento `change` del input:

```
<script>
$("input[name=vtoDias2]").on('change', function (e) {
  $('#numFecha3').html($(this).val());
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Excelente. Me funcionó perfecto. Gracias ^^